# Python Assignment Order

Tags: python

I am new to python. Can someone explain why the following two python example does not output the same thing?

Example 1

```
a, b = 0, 1
while b < 50:
    print(b)
    a, b = b, a + b
```

Example 2

```
a, b = 0, 1
while b < 50:
    print(b)
    a = b
    b = a + b
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the first version, when you write

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

the expression

```
b, a + b
```

is evaluated first. After it has been evaluated, it is subsequently assigned to `a, b` with tuple unpacking.  The key point is that the entire right hand side of an assignment statement is evaluated in its entirety before performing the binding of the left-hand side names.

In the second version,

```
a = b 
# a is now re-bound and potentially has changed value
```

is performed first, and then

```
b = a + b
# the expression a + b uses the modified value of a
```

happens after. By which point, `a` has been re-bound.

---

So, to illustrate with some values. The first time round the loop, after `a, b = 0, 1` we have

```
# a == 0
# b == 1
a, b = b, a + b
```

Now, `b, a + b` is `1, 1`. And so we have

```
a, b = 1, 1
```

But the alternative goes like this:

```
a = b 
# same as a = 1
b = a + b
# same as b = 1 + 1
```

---

You ask in a comment:

> How would Example 1 be rewritten into 2 statements?

The safest way is to introduce temporary variables. Like this:

```
a1 = b
b1 = a + b
# now we can assign to a and b
a = a1
b = b1
```

In this case you don't actually need two temporary variables, one will suffice, but this is the most general form.

---

This tuple unpacking is how you swap two values idiomatically in Python. In other languages you write:

```
temp = a
a = b
b = temp
```

In Python you write:

```
a, b = b, a
```

Comment: so how would Example 1 be rewritten into 2 statements?

Comment: @YTKColumba: temp = b; b = a+b; a = temp;